# "no java virtual machine was found" error after starting eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, environment-variables

When running eclipse, I get this error. "...no java virtual machine was found...". I have searched many threads and post and have set the JAVA_HOME system variable and virtual machine address in eclipse.ini as the posts said but still get that error. I'm really stuck and don't know what to do. please help me

Edit:
here is my eclipse.ini file"

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-Declipse.buildId=v21.0.0-531062
```

After changing the position of -vm line to the current position I get this new error:

```
 "java was started but returned exit code=13
 -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6"
```

Comment: perhaps post the `vm` line from the ini file

Comment: @alfasin: I said that I've read those questions and their solutions didn't worked for me.

Comment: @alireza when you run `java -version` from prompt - what do you get ?

Comment: @alfasin: I know this is stupid but yesterday I was getting 1.7.25 but no i get "java is not recognized as internal or external command"

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse does not use the `JAVA_HOME` environmental variable. Ensure that the `-vm` flag in `eclipse.ini` points to a valid `JVM`

Comment: I've done that. still get the error

Comment: Is `jdk1.7.0_25` listed as one of the installed JREs?

Comment: Does `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\javaw.exe` exist?

Comment: Yes it does and jre7 is in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar with eclipse after installing net beans.  None of the fixes that I had found seemed to work.  What I ended up having to do is uninstall all versions of Java and then re-installing them. I was running windows 8.

Comment: It seems that eclipse needs jdk 1.6 (jre 6). But the strange thing is that I can run a java code with scala IDE. (eclipse indigo)

Comment: I don't remember my exact error, sorry, but it was something similar wanting jdk 1.6, which I did have installed.  Like you I was able to still run java code, tried the -vm line in the ini file to no avail.   The only difference is I am using kepler release.